# WSo2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Which inbuilt key manager ,WSo2 API Manager uses  for managing access tokens. Is Ws02 Identity server built within API Manager.

I know that we can configure a third party key manager (with different Database) with WSo2 API Manager..but I am not sure what is the default key manager used in the API Manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, WSO2 Identity Server features are installed within API Manager. And if you have a WSO2 Identity Server node running separately, it can also [act as the key manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0).

Comment: Does it also have an App server by default..If so , how can I access it

Comment: It has some feature of AS. If if you want, you can install any AS feature in it. What is the feature you're looking for?

Comment: There is a button in the API Manager page " Deploy sample APP''. Clicking on it will deploys the Pizza Application using the local host. So I was wondering where the app was deployed. Can we deploy a SOAP or a REST web service within API Manager.

Comment: Please note that is "Deploy Sample API". However, it's backend webapp is deployed in APIM itself. You can find it at `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/' directory. IF you want to install any webapp, you can place it in the same place, and it will get deployed.

Comment: If you have any other questions, please post as separate questions, because lengthy conversations in comment section is discouraged in SO.